# iOS 7 iAd Implementation & iAd Network Temporarily Unavailable

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I have submitted three iOS apps and they have all been approved. I implemented iAd into them, and the test ads show when I test the apps. But now they have been on the App Store for a few days, and I haven't seen any ads when I download the apps on devices that are not provisioned as test devices. I have already accepted the iAd contract, and the iAd page simply says "iAd Network is temporarily unavailable Sorry: We were unable to locate information relating to your account. Please try again later".

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same issue , my app rolled out to the app store today.

Some people say that it takes a couple of days for production ads to show up in new apps
Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Please add this as a comment.